# Give Popup on Symbol Javascript Esri Map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, esri

I have a symbol marker on map. I want display popup when I click the symbol. 
My code:

```
        map = new Map("map", {  
          basemap: "satellite",  
          center: [139.736, 36.045], // longitude, latitude  
          zoom: 13  
        });  

        var symbol = new PictureMarkerSymbol({
            "url":"images/marker.png",
            "height":32,
            "width":32,
            "type":"esriPMS",
            "yoffset": 16,
        });     

         map.on("load", coordinates);   

         function coordinates() {  
            console.log("got here")  
             var lat, long;
             lat="36.045";
             long="139.736";
             var mp = new Point(long, lat);  
             var graphic = new Graphic(mp, symbol);  
             map.graphics.add(graphic);  
         }  

      });
```

How add popup on symbol?
Thank you